# dynamically or programmatically unmount / detach a persistent volum claim from a kubernetes pod and assign (mount /attach ) it to another pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, fabric8, fabric8-maven-plugin

I have a pod called `mypod0` with two persistent volumes.

`mypd0`, `mypd1` (provided through two persistent volume claims `myclaim0`, `myclaim1`) mounted into `mypod0` at `/dir0`, `/dir1` as shown in the pod definition below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod0
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mycontainer
      image: myimage
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/dir0"
        name: mypd
-   mountPath: "/dir1"
-   name: mypd1
  volumes:
    - name: mypd0
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: myclaim0
    - name: mypd1
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: myclaim1
```

Now I also have another pod `mypod1` already running in the cluster. Is there a way to **dynamically/programmatically** (using fabric8, Kubernetes-client) to unmount (detach) `mypd1` from `mypod0`, and then attach the volume `mypd1` into `mypod1` (without restarting any of the pods `mypod0`, `mypod1`). Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Nope, this is not possible. Pod-manifests is intended to be seen as immutable and pods as disposable resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As [Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213269/jonas) mentioned in the comment, this action is not possible:**

> Nope, this is not possible. Pod-manifests is intended to be seen as immutable and pods as disposable resources.

Look at the definition of [pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/):

> *Pods*  are the smallest deployable units of computing that you can create and manage in Kubernetes.
>
> A  *Pod*  (as in a pod of whales or pea pod) is a group of one or more  [containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/), with shared storage and network resources, and a specification for how to run the containers. A Pod's contents are always co-located and co-scheduled, and run in a shared context. A Pod models an application-specific "logical host": it contains one or more application containers which are relatively tightly coupled. In non-cloud contexts, applications executed on the same physical or virtual machine are analogous to cloud applications executed on the same logical host.

However, you can dynamically create new storage volumes. Kubernetes supports [Dynamic Volume Provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/):

> Dynamic volume provisioning allows storage volumes to be created on-demand. Without dynamic provisioning, cluster administrators have to manually make calls to their cloud or storage provider to create new storage volumes, and then create  [`PersistentVolume`  objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)  to represent them in Kubernetes. The dynamic provisioning feature eliminates the need for cluster administrators to pre-provision storage. Instead, it automatically provisions storage when it is requested by users.

Comment: so, let's say I have 1,2,3 stateful pods with remote volumes a,b,c, if I decided to kill 3 and assign its volume c to 2. There is no way to do that without killing/restating 2. Is that accurate?

Comment: Exactly. There is no way to do that without killing/restating pod.